# What is the SystemVerilog equivalent of the VHDL "library"?

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog

I have been writing VHDL for a while. There, we have the concept of libraries, which comes in handy. I cannot find something of this nature in SystemVerilog.

Is it true that SystemVerilog has no concept of compiling modules into different libraries like VHDL? If so, what is the closest equivalent of VHDL libraries?

Comment: There is a concept of importing a package and including a header file. You may wanna look into it.

Comment: I have found that we can create a package and then use `include and import to bring it into the our module. However, that is not my question.

Answer (score 1):

One of the differences between VHDL and SystemVerilog is that other than the definition of compilation units and configurations, SystemVerilog stays away from tool specific aspects of the compilation process.

The concept of a *library* usually involves organization of data in a physical filesystem. Most tools that compile SystemVerilog also compile VHDL and allow you to target source code into in different libraries in similar manner. You should look at the Unser manuals for the tools you are using.

Section *33. Configuring the contents of a design* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) does provide a way to specify library behavior from within the language. But there is currently no other way within the language to indicate which modules belong to which libraries.

Comment: Libraries (VHDL) are not tool specific and have no relationship to how files are organized on the file system. They are closer to C++ namespaces.

Comment: @user_1818839. that's true for VHDL, but not so much in SystemVerilog.

Comment: Do I understand correct that with SystemVerilog, all module exist in a flat hierarchy? There is also no concept of namespace? If so, then what happens if two modules have same name but is actually different module?

Comment: @quantum231, SystemVerilog has multiple namespaces as defined in section _3.13 Name spaces_. There is one global namespace for module names, but it's possible to tell the compiler to compile a module into a library, and then specify a ordered search list of libraries to scan for pre-compiled modules. None of that is specified in the LRM.

Comment: Where can I find a more details description of what the concept of library and namespace in SystemVerilog is like?

Comment: Section 33 in the LRM